# "Впечатление о"

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, лексическая-сочетаемость

Мне казалось, что *впечатление* совместимо только с родительным падежом (*впечатления детства*, *впечатление от события*). К своему удивлению обнаружил в Нацкорпусе 681 вхождение типа "впечатление о ком-то (о чем-то)".
Как это совместимо с тем, что говорит [словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x)?

> ВПЕЧАТЛЕНИЕ, -я; ср. 1. обычно мн.: впечатления, -ий. Образ, след, оставляемые в сознании, в памяти человека предметами и явлениями внешнего мира. Впечатления детства. Дорожные впечатления. Искать новых впечатлений. 2. Влияние, воздействие на кого-л. Находиться под впечатлением фильма. Производить сильное в. на кого-л. 3. Мнение, оценка, сложившиеся после знакомства, общения с кем-, чем-л. Делиться, обмениваться впечатлениями. Юноша оставил благоприятное в. Создаётся в., что ты не говорил с ним.

Неужели можно говорить "впечатление о предмете" вместо "мнение о предмете"?

> Владимир Путин поделился впечатлениями о Джордже Буше [Екатерина Григорьева. Расстановка акцентов. Владимир Путин поделился впечатлениями о Джордже Буше (2001) // «Известия», 2001.06.19]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Неужели можно говорить "впечатление о предмете" вместо "мнение о
>   предмете"?

Не совсем "вместо", но конечно можно. Это относится к п.3 приведенной Вами словарной статьи.

Приведу пример из другой статьи того же словаря (см. слово "портить").

> Портить показатели, сводку, отчётность, картину (снижать общее
>   благоприятное впечатление о чём-л.).

Comment: Из другого вопроса : "первые впечатления о будущей королеве". Здесь мн.ч. Это тоже  приемлемо?

Comment: @М_Г Тогда такой пример: "добрые впечатления о прошлом" (словарь тот же, статья "благодарный").

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь и этот словарь в п.3 говорит, что впечатление может быть синонимичным мнению. На мой взгляд, в контексте примера "впечатление" отличается от "мнения" большей осторожностью, диполоматичностью высказывания: это мнение не окончательное, а составленное или сложившееся поверхностно, в процессе первого общения, когда могли раскрыться лишь отдельные стороны человека. Это не "произведённое кем-то" впечатление, а "составленное себе" предварительное мнение.

Comment: А как тогда понимать " Ему присланы её портреты, и он в восторге описывает родителям свои первые впечатления о будущей королеве" (мн. ч.)? Набор предварительных мнений после просмотра? Или от каждого портрета свое впечатление (мнение)?

Comment: Первые впечатления здесь - что-то вроде отрывочных суждений и догадок об особе, изображение которой понравилось.